# Vertex AI Workbench User-managed notebooks crashing with Huggingface Datasets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-lab, google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, huggingface-datasets

I am attempting to load a **Huggingface** dataset in a **User-managed notebook** in the Vertex AI workbench. I have tried memory-optimized machines such as `m1-ultramem-160` and `m1-megamem-96`. I selected an additional **2000 GB** of SDD boot/disk space.

The dataset downloads about 60% of the way before JupyterLab crashes.

For example, this crashes the kernel:

`! pip install datasets`

```
pile_dataset = load_dataset('the_pile', 'all', split = 'train')
```

I am unsure if I need to do anything specific to increase the available memory allocated to the JupyterLab instance.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Currently replicating your issue. Can you share your [logs](https://i.imgur.com/B8xGtbq.png)?

Comment: Hi @AnjelaB , I have attached a link to a screenshot of the logs: [link](https://i.imgur.com/GxgzC38.png)